# Permission Denied Product Import Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import

I am receiving the following error while trying to import products that I have already imported before using the same file.

The error appears in one of the MessageManager's error boxes with a red cross.

Deleted that file manually does not help - it is recreated.

The file `C:/laragon/www/teststore/var/importexport/catalog_product.csv` cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(`C:/laragon/www/teststore/var/importexport/catalog_product.csv`): Permission denied

Comment: Facing same issue after adding new products, any solution u found ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe I had it open at the same time as trying to delete it? or the folder open?

Answer (score 2):

This error caused due to the existed attributes repeating in that import file.

So, Please check your .CSV file if any attribute is repeated. If yes, Delete those repeated attributes and import again.

Comment: Any solution for display error message instead of read report. I got this problem and loading.gif still running.